# add 10 query parametr in url + api asp.net mvc

Tags: api, url, model-view-controller, parameters

a have web api asp.net mvc and a method . this haved 10 parametrs.
if to send all parametrs , url is long!
like this : localhost:2264/api/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/1/4
whether exist other way that parametrs to send ?
api for application android
tanks

Comment: can you please show what have you tried, from where the params come ?

Comment: @owel1221 when you post a question try to specify what you have tried and issues that you ran into while doing those tries.